# Changing a subview's frame has no effect?

Tags: ios

I've got a subview on the right side of my view, that's only visible/onscreen in landscape mode (much like Facebook's chat view). Note that auto-layout is turned off.

I want to enable the user to reveal this view in portrait mode by swiping left.

[image]

Here's the view's autoresizing mask as set in Interface builder:

[image]

The red view is still visible, but to the right of the red view and off-screen.

Changing it's frame has no effect, except after turning back to landscape mode, and then the view keeps it's position even when turning to portrait mode. I'm guessing it's because of it's resize mask, but setting that to none doesn't help either.

```
-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)pan
{    
  [self.rightSideView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 
                                          self.rightSideView.frame.size.width,
                                          self.rightSideView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view's width changed from 256 pixels in landspace to 0 in portrait. Unsetting the flexible width solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self.rightSideView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 
                                          self.rightSideView.frame.size.width,
                                          self.rightSideView.frame.size.height)];
            });
```